# How to do a http post request faster in c#?

Tags: c#, http, http-post, httprequest

I'm having problems with my application in c#, I receive data from the internet every 20 milliseconds, and I need to process that data and make a  http post request with the processed data, but making the request takes much longer than receiving the data from the internet , this is my code:

```
//data comes from internet every 20 milliseconds
public static async Task CalculateHp(string data)
    {          
        var datos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataModel>(data);

        datos.hp = datos.rpm * datos.torque / 5252;
        datos.now = DateTime.Now;

        var jsonArray = new JArray();
        var jsonStringObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(datos);
        jsonArray.Add(JObject.Parse(jsonStringObject));
        var jsonStringArray = jsonArray.ToString();

        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();        
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.PostAsync("https://url", new StringContent(jsonStringArray, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        }
        long elapsedMilliseconds = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        //the value of elapsedMillisecons is approximately 500 milliseconds
        Console.WriteLine(elapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

Can anyone give me any suggestions or examples?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Upgrade your ISP? /s

Comment: @RyanWilson Then get many requests waiting to finish :)

Comment: @Eser lol..why not?    :P

Comment: Also, use a static instance of HttpClient instead of the `using()` statement. You might wind up with lots of open connections.

Comment: Andres, You may also think to redesign your code because making a request every 20 ms  seems to me a bad idea. Your site should provide a better mechanism to monitor some real time data

Comment: You could investigate what about the request is slow, eg if it's the DNS request, maybe you can use IP address directly? Or get a faster DNS setup.

Comment: @Eser is right, being able to rely on receiving and sending requests every 20ms sounds difficult, what happens when the GC runs, or the system burps for some reason.

Comment: Hi @Eser I did what @RyanWilson said and it works, I removed the `await` an `using` sentences, as @RyanWilson said, I'm not currently using the response, but I want an explanation why it is a bad idea, Could you explain me? I'm not familiar with this. Thank you.

Comment: As I said before, Suppose response is taking 40ms. After 1 min you will have ~25 non-finished tasks waiting for response. 
If you wait enough you can see that either your app or your system will be down.

Comment: Is @RyanWilson Solution a bad idea even if I don't expect a response?

Comment: Yes don't do it. You may be creating tasks faster before the responses arrives. But the initial bad idea is your solution. You can't even post requests at 20ms intervals. Your windows may not give you that precision. try it with Task.Delay(20) or Thread.Sleep(20). They don't wait 20ms..